# Мера сходства

Tags: семантика

Недавно в одной загадке я прочитала такое условие: 
"...но уже с другим эпитетом, с точностью до 3-х первых букв совпавшим с её фамилией.."

Как понять, что же совпало? Я поняла фразу так, что первые три буквы могли отличаться, а концы слов совпадали. Однако автор считал, что совпадают как раз первые три буквы.

Какое понимание фразы можно считать более правильным?

**Дополнение**. В каком случае слова совпадают "с точностью до 3-х первых букв"?

Мое понимание: "картон" и "пистон", три первых буквы отличаются, остальные совпадают.
Авторской понимание: "шанхайский" и "шанина" - три первых буквы совпадают.

Answer (score 3):

Логика автора задачи понятна. В математике фраза "с точностью до первых трёх знаков" означает, что первые три цифры совпадают, а далее могут быть расхождения. Правда автор не учёл, что буквы - не цифры и сугубо математическое клише к ним не применимо. Соответственно фразу можно понимать как в авторском варианте (помня клише), так и в языковом (3 первых буквы граница несовпадения, до них совпадает, про то что после неизвестно).

Чтобы добиться однозначности, автору достаточно переформулировать в - "...но уже с другим эпитетом, где первые 3 буквы совпадают с её фамилией.."

Answer (score 0):

Я согласна с автором. Концы фамилий у многих совпадают. А вот чтобы и первые несколько букв совпали - надо поискать.

Например, эпитетом, совпавшим полностью (до 3-х первых букв) может быть "резкая" и Резкая, "редкая" и "Редкая" и др. Такие слова вполне могут быть эпитетами и фамилиями.

А как выглядит фраза целиком? Заинтриговали)))

Comment: По-моему, вы отвечаете не на тот вопрос. Не требовалось полного совпадения. И фамилия тут ни при чем, это просто пример. Меня заинтересовали слова "с точностью до 3 первых букв" - что это может значить?  
Дополню в вопросе.

Comment: Понятно. Тогда 2-ой ответ (Яzz) правильный. От меня +1

Answer (score 0):

Я не совсем понял, о каком-таком "математическом понимании" Яzz говорил с математиком  DocentI...

Мое понимание таково. 
Выражение "с точностью до" в лингвистике как некий специальный термин не используется, а в математике и в быту означает одно и то же: область (множество) внутри которой ***условие выполняется***, а не наоборот. Вопрос в том, как понимать описание этой области.

Мое мнение таково.
Если сказано "С точностью до ***пятого*** знака", то это означает ***совпадение*** четырех первых знаков, а не наоборот. Касательно пятого - тут уже можно обсуждать, входит он в множество или нет.

Но если сказано "до ***одного (двух, трех)*** знаков", то как ни крути, речь идет о числе ***несовпадений***, все остальное должно совпадать. Таким образом, считаю, что формулировка задачи (т.е. мнение автора) ошибочна.

Есть еще "военное" понимание предлога "до", которое означает "примерно", "около", в таком случае "с точность до такого-то знака" означало бы "примерно до такого-то знака", но здесь оно явно невозможно.

Comment: Мы с еще одним решающим подумали еще вот о чем. Когда говорят "равно с точностью до константы" то эта-то константа как раз и не совпадает. То есть не совпадает то, "до чего". Думаю, автору просто не стоило использовать такое выражение. Меня, например, оно сильно замедлило в решении. Потому что фамилий, похожих на эпитеты (как говорит @Надюшка) совсем мало.

Comment: > То есть не совпадает то, "до чего".  
  
Двусмысленная фраза. Но я Вас понял. Не совпадает XXX, который фигурирует в обороте "с точностью до XXX" - и то, что "после" XXX. А то, что "до него" - как раз совпадает.    

>Думаю, автору просто не стоило использовать такое выражение.   
  
Естественно. Он ошибочно его понимает.